# Samsung Tab: Remote Debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I'm working on a web project which is converting the application into a Android/iOS App using a mechanism similar to PhoneGap.

The issues is that, I unable to debug the Android App (HTML/CSS/Javascript) by following the instructions @ https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Somehow, I'm not able to discover the USB devices in chrome://inspect/#devices. (P.S: While installing the Samsung Driver from http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T800NZWAXAR# ) the driver installation failed for CDC_Driver and Samsung_Android)

Device using: Samsung Galaxy Tab S (SM-T800) Android version - 4.2.2
Please advice.

Comment: Anyone ever managed to figure this one out? I currently have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this one. I guess it's 11 months to late for you though @TheNerd.

What is not mentioned in the guide is that you need to download a Android SDK.

It can be downloaded from here: [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

You should also make sure you have JDK on your computer. If you don't the SDK installer will notice and provide you with a link to download it from Oracle.

After installing the driver, the JDK and the SDK my computer was able to detect my device right away.